# Convert Angular to plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, capacitor-plugin

This is example code for a plugin to an Ionic/Capacitor/Angular project:

```
import { ForegroundService } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/foreground-service/ngx';


constructor(public foregroundService: ForegroundService) { }

...

startService() {
// Notification importance is optional, the default is 1 - Low (no sound or vibration)
  this.foregroundService.start ('GPS Running', 'Background Service', 'drawable/fsicon');
}

stopService() {
// Disable the foreground service
  this.foregroundService.stop();
}
```

I'm not familiar with Angular, and there's no plain JavaScript (not Typescript) example. How would this code look in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Ionic expert, but after reading [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/foreground-service) I bet that it should be used like this:

```
// import without `ngx`
import { ForegroundService } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/foreground-service';

// create the object from class
const foregroundService = new ForegroundService();

// start the service
foregroundService.start('GPS Running', 'Background Service', 'drawable/fsicon');

// stop the service
foregroundService.stop()
```

[Learn more about using Ionic Native components in React](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react) section was particularly useful

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure you are right. I got confused by the `constructor` line.